# Strange bright light in the sky flying fast

Tags: planet, light, space

I was out with my dad on our porch watching the stars with our telescope. after awhile of looking and taking pictures I noticed something strange in the sky. There were two airplanes flying close to each other, but next to those two airplanes was a very bright light (see how the stars are bright? Well that one was a lot bigger and I lot brighter, and to give you an example it was moving as fast as the planes, I showed my dad and he as well saw it, so I knew I wasn’t dreaming, it wasn’t moving straight either, both me and my dad could see it was going in zigzags, not a straight line, it desapeared after awhile behind he trees, we didn’t get to look at it through the telescope since it was moving so fast...what could it be...? Both me and my dad agree it was going as fast as the planes next to it, it was brighter then both the planes and the stars and it could not have been a third plane since broth planes were just so small and it looked like a very big star. FINALY it was not moving in a straight line...so the what would it be...?

Comment: Celestial objects don't zigzag.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds kind of like a [Foo Fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo_fighter). 
There have been various reports of weird glowing orbs following aircraft and zig-zagging around them ever since World War two. In fact both sides assumed they were secret weapons belonging to the other side up until the end of the war.

As to what they actually are exactly, well *nobody really knows*. The most plausible answer is that these are examples of [Ball lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning) or some other electrostatic phenomenon. As far as I know, it has never been conclusively replicated in the lab.